# Making my first batch, but don't have bottles

Tags: fermentation, beer, brewing, bottles

I'm making my first batch of beer to try out brewing. The kit I have produces 20 pints but unfortunately I don't have bottles to put the beer into afterwards.

Is there any other way of storing the beer? I will only be storing it for about a month before consuming it.

Could I store them in Glass Clip Lid Jars?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use "Glass Clip Lid" jars, aka Mason jars, aka canning jars.  Apparently they cannot hold the pressure required for carbonated beer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have bottling gear (bottles, capper, caps, bottle tree etc)

Your alternatives need to hold about 15 psi, and be easy to sanitize.

2 liter soda bottles work nice, just need to keep the beer out of the light.

Sometimes you can find flip top bottles (grolsch style) at .99 cent stores. Brown bottles are a rare find cheap so again no light. LHBS should be able to get them.

Start saving retail beer bottles and get some bottling equipment.

Ultimately we like to keg our beer. But there's a lot of upfront costs. (corny keg, c02 tank, regulator, tap, lines and a place to refridgerate it)